# C#, Trying to pull prime numbers from generated array all I get is 0

Tags: c#, arrays, output, primes

> The program will generate a sequence of randomly chosen numbers between 1 – 100. The sequence will consist of 20 elements.
> Your program should display the sequence once it is generated.
> Then, it will display all prime numbers within this sequence.

The code so far:

```
class Program

    {
        int[] rnum = new int[100];
        int[] selecting = new int[20];
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program myProgram = new Program();
            myProgram.Numbers();
            myProgram.PrimeN();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public void Numbers()
        {
            int[] rnum = new int[100];
            // Filling the array with values 1 to 100:
            for (int i = 0; i < rnum.Length; i++)
            {
                rnum[i] = i + 1;
            }
            // Shuffling the elements of the array:
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < rnum.Length; i++)
            {
                int j = rnd.Next(i, rnum.Length);
                int temp = rnum[i];
                rnum[i] = rnum[j];
                rnum[j] = temp;
            }
            // Selecting and presenting 20 numbers:
            int[] selecting = new int[20];
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                selecting[i] = rnum[i];
            selecting.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write(i.ToString() + ", "));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        public void PrimeN()
        {
            
            List<int> primeNumbers = new List<int>();           
            for (int i = 0; i < selecting.Length; i++)
            {
                if (IsPrime(selecting[i]))
                {
                 
                    primeNumbers.Add(selecting[i]);
                }
            }
            Console.Write("Non-Prime Numbers:");
            for (int i = 0; i < primeNumbers.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(primeNumbers[i] + " ");
  
            }
         
        }
        bool IsPrime(int number)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < Math.Sqrt(number); i++)
            {
                if (number % i == 0) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created local variable called `selecting` inside `Numbers()` function. Scope of this local variable is within `Numbers()` function.

When you are trying to read same variable in `PrimeN()`, it is referring to the globally defined `selecting` variable.

As there is nothing stored in global `selecting` variable you are getting 0 as result in `primeNumbers` array.

To Solve this issue, do not create local variable called `selecting` inside `Numbers()` function, use globally defined variable i.e. `selecting` defined at class level

```
...

public void Numbers()
{
    ...
    // Selecting and presenting 20 numbers:
    //COMMENT BELOW LINE
    //int[] selecting = new int[20];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        selecting[i] = rnum[i];   //This will refer member which is defined globally
    selecting.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write(i.ToString() + ", "));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Beautifully explained

Comment: I am glad my answered solved your issue. Cheers and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see, is you are creating local variables, instead of using the instance members you have declared, after your method runs, nothing gets changed... it all happened locally in the method.

Comment out the below lines, you have already declared them

```
public static void Numbers(int size)
{
   //int[] rnum = new int[size];

   ...

   //int[] selecting = new int[20];
```

Though it could all be reduced to

```
private static readonly Random _r = new Random();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var numbers = Generate(100);
   var selected = numbers.Take(20).ToArray();
   Console.WriteLine("Selected : " + string.Join(", ", selected));
   Console.Write("Primes : " + string.Join(",", selected.Where(IsPrime)));
   Console.ReadLine();
}

public static int[] Generate(int size)
{
   var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();
   // Shuffling the elements of the array:
   for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
   {
      var j = _r.Next(i, numbers.Length);
      var temp = numbers[i];
      numbers[i] = numbers[j];
      numbers[j] = temp;
   }

   return numbers;
}

private static bool IsPrime(int number)
{
   for (var i = 2; i < Math.Sqrt(number); i++)
      if (number % i == 0) return false;
   return true;
}
```

**Output**

```
Selected : 92, 79, 1, 44, 83, 48, 70, 49, 80, 19, 27, 65, 50, 40, 20, 10, 68, 25, 9, 28
Primes : 79,1,83,49,19,25,9
```

Comment: Just started learning so I still have a long way to go but this gives me a very good insight.

Comment: Thank you! looks much cooler in your version, but I probably shouldn't use it as it is my first assignment . That said this teaches me a lot thank you very much.

Comment: @AkosAndras all good, you can just search for each method, to understand what they do for future reference. Great way to learn, basically these are just a few linq examples